# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, exception, program-entry-point, arithmeticexception

I have two questions about `Exceptions`. Firstly, I got this message from my code...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

This error message means dividing by zero, such as by doing `int a = 5 / 0;`

A method can throw an `Exception` class instance, can't it? But this is an expression. Why can an expression throw an `Exception` class instance ?

My second question is about `thread "main"`. What is `thread "main"`? Does `"main"` mean the `static main` method?

Answer (score 4):

`java.lang.ArithmeticException` is a type of `Exception` that aims to better describe what the problem actually is. There's no point just creating an `Exception`, as it really could be caused by anything. By generating an `ArithmeticException`, the user can immediately know that the problem is something to do with a calculation. An `Exception` can be thrown by any piece of code, including in calculations such as your example.

`Exception in thread "main"` means that the exception is thrown by the `main()` method, which also happens to be the primary Thread that is running your code.

Answer (score 2):

*Method can throw exception class instance, isn't it?*

Yes they can.

*But this is statement. Why can statement throw exception class instance ?*

Exception can occur anywhere. So even statements can throw exceptions. And in case you meant why can't statements throw exceptions,well they can. Here's an example:

```
if ((a/b) == 0) {
        throw new ArithmeticException();
    }
```

*Second question is about thread "main". What is thread "main" ?*

When a Java program starts up, one thread begins running immediately. This is usually called the main thread of your program, because it is the one that is executed when your program begins.

Answer (score 0):

Its Arithmetic exception case: means something in logic which **not exist in Mathematical arithmetic;**

Check the condition of the "for loop" or any other logical functions.

An example is when somewhere you write something like: `(n % i == 0)` and give initialization `i = 0`, now every one knows that number can not be divided by Zero. So, you may need to change the initialization to `i = 1`.